# Why does my Flask-React app's sign-up page generate 2 requests when submitting a form?

Tags: reactjs, flask, post, backend, form-submit

I am linking my backend with frontend for a Flask-React app's sign-up page.
I have an SQLite database linked to my backend Flask app.
Currently, when I enter the fields on the sign up page (username, email, password, confirm password), and hit submit, it surprisingly generates 2 requests: 1 that fails and 1 that succeeds. The failed request returns status code 500 with POST method. The payload of what I entered is visible.

The succeeded request returns status code 200 with OPTIONS method. The payload is not visible and Preview and Response under the Chrome Network's page shows Failed to load response data.

My frontend is coded to clear the fields after processing the request but that doesnt happen.

I don't understand why an OPTIONS method was cited when I only included POST in my code.

When I send in another identical form submission, which the backend will reject because an identical email already exists in the database from the 1st form submission, the fields are cleared as intended, the payload is visible, and Preview and Response indicate that the Signup was unsuccessful as intended.

I do not understand why my valid submission made 2 requests and failed to display my input in the Payload/Preview/Response sections, while my subsequent invalid submission seems to work correctly. This happens on Microsoft Edge as well. I have also made sure to only call CORS once.

Back-end code:

```
@auth.route('/sign-up', methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin()
def sign_up():
    data = request.json
    email = data.get('email')
    username = data.get('username')
    #name = request.form.get('name')
    password1 = data.get('password1')
    password2 = data.get('password2')
    #check
    #return jsonify({"message": "DONE"}), 200
    # email = request.form.get('email')
    # username = request.form.get('username')
    # #name = request.form.get('name')
    # password1 = request.form.get('password1')
    # password2 = request.form.get('password2')

    #### Validating Infomation
    # check to make sure that user doesn't already exist
    user = session.query(models.User).filter_by(username=username).first()
    print(user)
    if user:
        flash('Email already exists.', category='error')
        return jsonify({"error": "Signup unsuccessful"}), 500

    # message flashing: flash a msg on screen using flask, import flash
    if len(email) < 4:
        # tell user there's an issue
        flash('Email must be greater than 3 characters', category='error')
        return jsonify({"error": "Signup unsuccessful"}), 500
    elif len(username) < 4:
        flash('Username must be greater than 3 characters', category='error')
        return jsonify({"error": "Signup unsuccessful"}), 500
    # elif len(name) < 2:
    #     flash('Name must be greater than 1 character', category='error')
    elif password1 != password2:
        flash('Passwords don\'t match.', category='error')
        return jsonify({"error": "Signup unsuccessful"}), 500
    elif len(password1) < 7:
        flash('Password must be at least 7 characters', category='error')
        return jsonify({"error": "Signup unsuccessful"}), 500
    else:
        # add user to database
        #I removed name=name
        newUser = models.User(email=email, username=username, password=generate_password_hash(password1, method='scrypt'))
        # sha256, scrypt are hashing algorithms, there's others as well
        session.add(newUser) # add user to database
        # commit to the database
        session.commit()
        login_user(newUser, remember=True)
        flash('Account created!', category='success')

        # redirect user to home page
        return jsonify({
            "email": newUser.email,
            "username": newUser.username,
            "password": newUser.password
            # "name": newUser.name,
        }), 200
```

Front-end code:

```
const SignUp = () => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
    const [password1, setPassword1] = useState("");
    const [password2, setPassword2] = useState("");

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the form from submitting normally
    
        // Create a data object with the user's input
        const data = {
          email,
          username,
          password1,
          password2,
        };
    
        try {
          // Send a POST request to the backend endpoint '/sign-up'
          const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/sign-up', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
          })
          
          if (response.ok) {
            // Success response from the backend
            const jsonData = await response.json();
            console.log(jsonData)
            // Do something with the response data if needed
            setEmail("RIGHT");
          } else {
            // Error response from the backend
            setEmail("WRONG");
            console.error('Error:');
            // Handle the error case accordingly
          }
        
          //setEmail("");
          setUsername("");
          setPassword1("");
          setPassword2("");
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error:', error);
          // Handle any network or other errors
        }
          
      };
    return (
        <div>
            <div className = "signUpTitle">
                Begin your workout by signing up today!
            </div>

            /*Sign-in Credentials*/
            <div className = "signUpCreds">
                    <p>
                    <label for = "signUpUsername">
                        Choose a Username (8-16 characters long):
                    </label>
                    <input 
                      type = "text" 
                      id = "signUpUsername" 
                      name = "signUpUsername" 
                      value={username}
                      onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
                    />
                    </p>

                    <p>
                    <label for = "signUpEmail">
                        Enter your email:
                    </label>
                    <input 
                      type = "text" 
                      id = "signUpEmail" 
                      name = "signUpEmail" 
                      value = {email}
                      onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                    />
                    </p>
                
                    <p>
                    <label for = "signUpPassword">
                        Choose a Password (8-16 characters long):
                    </label>
                    <input 
                    type = "password" 
                    id = "signUpPassword" 
                    name = "signUpPassword" 
                    value = {password1}
                    onChange={(e) => setPassword1(e.target.value)}
                    />
                    </p>

                    <p>
                    <label for = "signUpPassword2">
                        Confirm Password:
                    </label>
                    <input 
                    type = "password" 
                    id = "signUpPassword2" 
                    name = "signUpPassword2" 
                    value = {password2}
                    onChange={(e) => setPassword2(e.target.value)}
                    />
                    </p>
              </div>

                {/*Submit Button*/}
                <div className = "submitSignUp" onClick={handleSubmit}>
                    <input type="submit" value="Sign Up Now!" />
                </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default SignUp
```

Comment: It could be that you have Strict Mode enabled on your react app. That would cause the requests to happen twice.